# How to validate JSON Schema according to Draft v4 using JSON.NET Schema or NJSONSchema?

Tags: validation, json.net, jsonschema, njsonschema

I have been looking into both [JSON.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) and [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema). Both don't seem to have any property / method that identifies if a JSON Schema is a valid one and in accordance with draft v4.

Is it that only an exception will identify if a schema is valid, and even if it's valid, how will I check that it's draft v4 compatible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON schema that describes JSON schema and use that to validate the JSON.

You can find a copy here - http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/api/jsonschemastore/schema?schemaUrl=schema-draft-v4

```
string draftV4SchemaJson = @"{}"; // replace with content from http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/api/jsonschemastore/schema?schemaUrl=schema-draft-v4

JSchema draftV4Schema = JSchema.Parse(draftV4SchemaJson);

JObject yourSchemaJson = JObject.Parse(@"{}"); // your schema

bool valid = yourSchemaJson.IsValid(draftV4Schema);
```

Comment: Yes i did, JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson); will tell me that schema itself is invalid only if an exception will occur , is'nt there another way to determine that schema itself ontains errors ?

Comment: I see. What you can do is validate the JSON you want to load as a schema with a schema that describes the v4 draft. I updated my answer.